# How to use this theme in LightSwitch 2012 project

Tags: silverlight, themes, visual-studio-lightswitch

I just found this theme http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/09/09/silverlight-jetpack-theme-released.aspx which you can download within this package http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14590.

But, the VSIX addon files are not compatible with VS 2012, and I have no idea how I may use the raw XAML files in my project.

Hope anybody can help out, and I can use this one in my project!

Best regards,
Simon

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not that easy to just *use* a Silverlight theme in LightSwitch.

I've been meaning to create some new LightSwitch themes to add to my [Luminous Themes for LightSwitch](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/10bc78be-f465-4b38-9b61-d66aa0b137e4) extension, but I just haven't had time.

Adapting the available Silverlight themes for use in LightSwitch is on my *to do* list. My themes are made available to the community at no cost.

Themes similar to what you want are available as a paid product at [LightSwitch Extras](http://www.lightswitchextras.com/).